# Are there NLP tools for text analysis?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Are there any tools on Ubuntu that can be used for Natural Language Processing? I am not necessarily looking for R, python or java scripts (thought they could be valuable), but for command line tools. It would be nice to have a tool, for instance, that would allow us to do extract keywords (not just counts, but probabilistic ones) or n-grams from a text.

I have already looked into http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/tools/alchemycmd/ but that is not open source (and I can't find a download).

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [Rapidminer Studio](https://rapidminer.com/products/studio/) but in version 5 since the version 6 is more commercial. You may find it on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rapidminer/). There is also a command-line mode, but you possibly need to create a process beforehand in the GUI.